# I feel like my IP is being targeted and under "web page hijacking" attacks

Tags: browser, ip, webpage, hijack

I tried:

1. Reinstalling browsers like Chrome, I don' t use IE so forget it;
2. Scanning Hard disk, Operating memory and Boot sector for virus;
3. Dumping BIOS to a file and scan it with VirusTotal;
4. Formatting whole hard disk **except** the recovery partition;
5. Using computer protection to install softwares;
6. Using Internet protection to surf Internet;
   Scanning results are all the same - no virus found.
   None of them avoids the hijacking.

So what I can conclude is this:

1. My IP is being targeted somehow by someone ridiculously;
2. My IP is constantly under web page hijacking attacks;
3. Whatever website I go, that website is hijacked as follows:

   1. Google Search result page search bar is hijacked;

   [image]

   2. A "pop-up tab" (`<div>` tag) transparent trap is added to HTML code;
   3. The trap covers the whole webpage, i.e. cannot bypass/ignore it.

   [image]

This is unbelievable.
I need help seriously.
What can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to change your IP and you have no special set up such as static requests with your ISP then turn off and unplug your router for ~20 minutes / 30 minutes and then reconnect, your ISP will (probably) give you a new IP address when your account is relogged on.

   Try doing this at busy times of day (early evening) to maximise the chances of a new IP being given to you.
2. If you have a special arrangement with your ISP such as a static IP address, then call them up and ask them to give you a new IP address. Then do the process described in **1**.
3. Download and run a genuine and reviewed/reliable Anti-virus program. I use [Eset](http://www.eset.co.uk/), but it's not free.
4. Download and run [MalwareBytes Anti-Malware](https://www.malwarebytes.com/). It is free and targets malware rather than known viruses.
5. It may be a wifi interference, if you're using wifi, you should change ALL your `computer --> router` passwords and then log into your router and tell your router to "not broadcast". also change your router's SSID name. You will no longer see it on your Laptop OS but you will need to manually type the name in and then the new password, this is far more secure than open, broadcasting wifi.
6. If all the above do not work at all, the next step would be to check if your router has been compromised, see if you can find any news/reviews on the internet and then see if you have another brand/model of router you can use to connect. Then carry out step **5**.

---

To further confirm if it is your specific IP address that is targetted get a friends laptop/iPad to connect to your router and your wifi. Do they have the same issues you are experiencing?

---

It looks like you're on a crappy version of windows (XP?) . I would highly recommend up/down-grading to Windows 7 or windows 10 to avoid security flaws. Windows 8 does **not** come recommended.

Comment: Why does this get a downvote? Let me know and things can be improved

Comment: I am using win7 sp1. I tried eset smart security and malwarebytes already. I use my phone' s wifi. My phone is fine but my pc is totally messed up, I don' t know why.